# How to find any keyword in same regex in preg_match php

Tags: php, regex, find

I have a text file and I want to search it like There are many lines in the file and I want to search each line, that it should return that line has the keyword "function" and that function should be called from the same line.

means I want to search keyword in same same regex.
for eg. please check following `test.txt` if line 2 of txt file has `function f3` but in that line there are no any calling function of `f3`, so that line should not be count.
but line 3 of text file has `function f1` and `f1()` also called from same line so it will be count.

the following is the file content from which I want to search lines.

`test.txt`

```
$xwbl209= "SN),AK mtyCcMXQHJ.T0-3qjfY5GnRl";
$k =5; function f3($a,$b,$c){ /*...*/ };
function f1(){ /*...*/ }; $a=1; $b=5; f1();
$aayw572 = f3($xwbl209{5},'',$xwbl209{10});
$k=10; function f2(){ /*...*/ }; $j=1; f1();
$bhzs038 = f3($xwbl209{5},$xwbl209{6},$xwbl209{8});
$aa = "aa"; function f4(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();
$b = "b"; function f5(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();
$aa = "aa"; function f6(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f6();
$bhzs038 = f3($xwbl209{5},$xwbl209{6},$xwbl209{8});
```

From the code below I was trying.

```php
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));
$new_line = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(preg_match(/somthing pattern/, $line)){
        $new_line[] = $line;    
    }
}
print_r($new_line);
```

I also tried the following pattern, but it doesn't work.
`/function ([^\(])+\(.*$1\(\).*/g`

The output of `$new_line` should be as follow.

```
function f1(){ /*...*/ }; $a=1; $b=5; f1();
$aa = "aa"; function f4(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();
$aa = "aa"; function f6(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f6();
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be using

```
\bfunction\h+(\w+\([^()]*\)).*\1;
```

**Explanation**

- `\bfunction\h+` A word boundary, match `function` and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+\([^()]*\)` Match 1+ word chars and from `(`...`)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `.*\1;` Match in the same line what is captured in group 1 using a backreference `\1` followed by `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C0DHKT/1)

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));
$new_line = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(preg_match('/\bfunction\h+(\w+\([^()]*\)).*\1;/', $line)){
        $new_line[] = $line;
    }
}
print_r($new_line);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => function f1(){ /*...*/ }; $a=1; $b=5; f1();
    [1] => $aa = "aa"; function f4(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();
    [2] => $aa = "aa"; function f6(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f6();
)
```

---

Or a shorter variation using [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$lines = file_get_contents('test.txt');
preg_match_all('/^.*?\bfunction\h+(\w+\([^()]*\)).*\1;/m', $lines, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have one more question can i find those lines which has the function called multiple time in same line ? like `function f1(){ /*...*/ }; $a=1; $b=5; f1(); $b=1; f1(); $c="test"`

Comment: I tried this `function (\w+\().*\1.*\1.*\1` but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @BhavikHirani In that case you could use `\bfunction\h+(\w+\([^()]*\)).*\1;.*\1;`  see https://regex101.com/r/BuMbrq/1

Answer (score 0):

A little tricky to catch with parameterized functions. You can first match all function declarations for a particular snippet. Later you could match function names only to see if they are called. Even if one among the matches is called, we add that line in result.

```
<?php

$result = [];

foreach(explode("\n",file_get_contents('test.txt')) as $line){
    preg_match_all('/\bfunction ([^\(]+)/',$line,$matches);
    foreach($matches[1] as $function_name){
        if(preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote($function_name) . '\((.+?)\);/',$line)){
            $result[] = $line;
            break;
        }
    }
}


print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

No looping is necessary.  You don't need to break your txt file into an array of lines.

The `m` modifier allows `^` to match the start of any line.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qaAgJ))

```
$text = <<<'TEXT'
$xwbl209= "SN),AK mtyCcMXQHJ.T0-3qjfY5GnRl";
$k =5; function f3($a,$b,$c){ /*...*/ };
function f1(){ /*...*/ }; $a=1; $b=5; f1();
$aayw572 = f3($xwbl209{5},'',$xwbl209{10});
$k=10; function f2(){ /*...*/ }; $j=1; f1();
$bhzs038 = f3($xwbl209{5},$xwbl209{6},$xwbl209{8});
$aa = "aa"; function f4(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();
$b = "b"; function f5(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();
$aa = "aa"; function f6(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f6();
$bhzs038 = f3($xwbl209{5},$xwbl209{6},$xwbl209{8});
TEXT;

var_export(
    preg_match_all(
        '~^.*?\bfunction\h+(\w+\([^()]*\)).*\b\1.*~m',
        $text,
        $out
    )
    ? $out[0]
    : ''
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'function f1(){ /*...*/ }; $a=1; $b=5; f1();',
  1 => '$aa = "aa"; function f4(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f4();',
  2 => '$aa = "aa"; function f6(){ /*...*/ }; $b=1; f6();',
)
```

Comment: If you have real strings that are missed or incorrectly matched, please improve your sample data to reflect the necessary complexity  and fringe cases.